# Determine the set of points at which the function is continuous:

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Determine the set of points at which the function is continuous: $f(x,y,z) = \sqrt{y-x^2} \cdot \ln z$.

I know that $y-x^2$ must be $\geq 0$ (because of the square root). I also know that $z>0$ (because of the natural log) but how would I go about finding the set of points where the entire function is continuous? Just having some trouble merging my ideas together.

Are my above thoughts correct?

Comment: The function is continuous where it is defined.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but the question asks for the specific set of points. How can I show those?

Comment: Just write the intervals where the function is defined that that should be answer

Comment: but how do we do that when we have 3 variables? normally you can easily write intervals where it is defined with 1 but this is more confusing with 3.